# Deny access to removable storage media for Windows XP client machines via Group Policy

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, removable-storage

I am currently editing a GPO for user accounts of a particular OU and I want to disable removable drives access on a particular OU, problem is that all the client machines are Windows XP and the **currently available policy works for clients that have Vista or above.**

How do I achieve this without having to manually go around all the machines and setting the local computer policy to not allow access to removable drives *(which will be my last ditch effort if nothing else works but its going to be a big headache)*?

Comment: damn just realized that policy doesn't exist in windows xp (locally either!)

Answer (score 1):

[Found a post](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/disable_usb_sticks) shows me a workaround how to do it! Hurray on to using the solution!

Comment: You should consider editing this and provide a summary of the solution you found in that blog. Links don't always stay up. Then you should consider marking this as your answer. :D